# My Genshin Impact PS4 trophies list is in Chinese, how to fix that?

Tags: achievements, ps4, genshin-impact

Title sums up pretty well.
I played a little when *Genshin Impact* was launched and I chose to wait for a European language localization for the PS4 trophies list since I couldn't understand any of them.

A year has passed, and I still have the Chinese list which sounds like a bug to me. Also because its trophies are listed in English on [PSN Profiles](https://psnprofiles.com/trophies/11500-genshin-impact) and other sites.

Is there a way to change PS4 trophies language from Chinese?

Comment: Which version of the game are you actually running? Generally, the various regional versions have separate trophy lists.

Comment: @pboss3010 EU, I have an Italian account

Comment: As far as I know, the trophy list is from the first time it pulled it from the servers. Example : I prefer to play my Assassins Creed games in french, so I switch my console to French but all achievements stay in english still because first time i loaded the game, it was in english. So I guess thats whats happening here. First time it pulled the achievements it was in the chinese, original version, and now its stuck that way.

Comment: @Fredy31 uhm thanks, sounds plausible.. I need to test this with another account.

Comment: There is a bunch of threads on different forums i've seen, and nobody had a solution. Only thing I saw was delete the game (savegame and data) fully and redownload it, but i'm not even sure that works.

Comment: @Fredy31 yep, I did a lot of research before asking here with no avail. I have earned no trophy yet, so I can still delete the trophy list, but that doesn't work either.